# Drawing Shapes in CSS

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

Any idea how to create that shape in CSS an how to keep it always centered while resizing ??

[image: description of the problem]

Comment: And you have not tried anything?

Comment: At the time im thinking about using translateX() and rotate() http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dCKcs

Comment: Problem is that rotate applies to the center of the div…

Comment: The Common solution to this Problem, using border-top and broder-right with a transparent value doesnt work in my particular case http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsaLc

Comment: Found a possible Solution: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsaLc

Comment: @muro The `transform:rotate` does not have to be from the center. You can use `transform-origin` to rotate about any point of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is to use transforms and set the transform-origin on the "fixed" point, here top right so :

```
transform-origin:100% 0;
```

Then you can rotate or skew your element :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/6Lwh38h9/)**

*HTML :*

```
<div></div>
```

*CSS :*

```
body{
    background:gold;
}
div{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    right:50%; top:0;
    background:teal;
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform-origin:100% 0;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-20deg);
    transform: skewX(-20deg);
}
```

Comment: Thank you web-tiki. Your solution is much better. Didnt known about `transform-origin:100% 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect Solution and needs some modification but should do the trick:

```
.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
   margin-left:-1000px;
   width: 4000px;
   height: 2000px;
   background-color: yellow;
}
.arrow {
   width: 0;
   height: 0;
   border-top: 2000px solid red;
   border-right: 2000px solid transparent;
}
```

You can see it here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vsaLc